# bash script to list the contents of a directory, separated by commas

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I need a bash script that lists files recursively in a directory in the following way:

```
filename,size (in kb),numeric value (in filename)
```

e.g.:

```
/directory/1/file-100.txt,50,100
/directory/1/file-200.txt,45,200
/directory/2/file-100.txt,20,100
/directory/2/file-500.txt,100,500
```

Also, I need it to ignore directories that start with "`.svn`"

Comment: `tree` might come in handy, but beyond that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe not the best way but should work:

```
find /path -type f | grep -v '.svn' | xargs du -k |\
  awk '{print $2","$1}' | sed 's/-\([0-9]*\)\(\..*\)/-\1\2,\1/'
```

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```
find -name ".svn" -prune -o -type f -printf "%p,%k,\n" | sed 's/\([^-]\+-\([0-9]\+\)\..*\)/\1\2/'
```

Only two utilities used (GNU versions probably required).

Answer (score 0):

**Features:**

- Avoid possible expensive traverse down .svn-dirs.
- Have find report size instead of 'du'
- Make awk do some more magic, no need for sed.

**Suggestion on solution:**

```
$ find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -printf '%p %k\n' |\
  awk -v OFS=, '{ print $1, $2, gensub(/[^0-9]*([0-9]*)/, "\\1", "g", $1) }'
```

**find-options:**

- *-path ...* Match .svn directories
- *-prune* If match (-path) is a directory, don't descend.
- *-o* ... Or ...
- *-type f* Match files only.
- *-printf ...* Print a custom line containing path (%p) and size in 1K-blocks (%k).

**awk:**

- *OFS=* What separator to use for fields when printing, instead of whitespace.
- *$1* Filepath
- *$2* Filesize
- *gensub(...)* Sorry, see http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/String-Functions.html

**Edit:** Updated per Dennis suggestion. Can't believe I missed %k actually, I blame 3AM.

Comment: You could set `OFS=,`. `find` can `-printf %k` so you don't have to do the division in AWK.